# Package clearance for CentOS 7.3

Tags: centos, rhel

Just wanted to confirm if we can install packages released by RHEL into CentOS or Vise versa if the versions are same for packages? We are using rhel 7.2 and centos 7.3 in 2 diff product and i wanted to have single patch every month which fixes the vulnerabilities for both the OS version.

Comment: Anecdotally, I have discovered some differences in the way binaries are compiled. For example, some commands may have curses support on RHEL but not on CentOS. The two operate like one another, but there *are* subtle binary differences.

Answer (score 2):

You might be aware that CentOS Linux distribution is a platform derived from the sources of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL). So, packages taken from Centos repo should work on RHEL and vice versa if versions are same.

Refer:

- https://www.centos.org/about/
- http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/440

Note that if you install anything non-RHEL into your supported RHEL installation, you may lose official support. A CentOS package installed on a RHEL system will not be supported by Red Hat.

See:

- [Production Support Scope of Coverage](https://access.redhat.com/support/offerings/production/soc)
  (*"Not supported: Community projects upon which enterprise releases are based."*)
- [How to use Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL)?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3358)
  (*"Installing unsupported packages does not necessarily make a system unsupportable by Red Hat Global Support Services. However, Red Hat Global Support Services will be unable to support or debug problems with packages not shipped in standard RHEL channels."*)